# Symfoy2 Sonata page bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I am trying to install Page Bundle From Sonata Project with the help of their doc here : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/page/2-x/doc/reference/installation.html. For some reasons i cant install it because when i make this command **php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataPageBundle** i get this error **Fatal error: Class 'Sonata\PageBundle\SonataPageBundle' not found in C:\www\SDIN\app\AppKernel.php on line 28**

Thanks for your help

Comment: `composer install` ? or make sure you have it in your vendors/composer.json. Empty cache maybe ?

Comment: i guess that is the problem in fact i can't use the composer due to proxy issues

Comment: And i don't have a composer in vendors ! i have in Web !